# HTML forms make image to a checkbox

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to make a HTML forms checkbox to a clickable image that is one image when initialized and another when clicked on. It should also be able to store one or two variables on it (because I need to generate them with a row and column variable on them) and work with the submit button.

Also sorry if this is a really easy question, I normally only work with C# and a bit of PHP when it is needed, but this time I'm forced to work with html and CSS, which I never was good at.

Comment: please post your code, what you have tried so far, HTML and CSS. Also clarify what you mean about storing variables ; are you using javascript? Input boxes will allow user input but what are you need to process that information. If this is 2 questions combined, you should ask two questions, and not bundle them into one

Comment: Thing is I literally have almost no knowledge with html and CSS and what I am trying to do is the following: 
The order.php gets fed two value one being for rows(x) the other for columns(y) then i need to create x rows and y columns of images that change when clicked on and when the user finally decides to click submit the finalize.php file must get all the information on what images were clicked.
Regarding the "post your code" part, the only thing I could post is my order.php file which shouldn't help this case since It only has the basic GUI yet.

Comment: If you haven't tried at all to make the form yet, please do some research and try first before posting a question. There's plenty of resources out there. This is not a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple starter for you, you can wrap this in a form:

```css
.checkbox-toggle {
 display: none;
}
.checkbox-toggle + img {
 display: inline-block;
}
.checkbox-toggle + img + img {
 display: none;
}
.checkbox-toggle:checked + img {
 display: none;
}
.checkbox-toggle:checked + img + img {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>
 <input class="checkbox-toggle" type="checkbox" name="img[0][0]" />
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100" />
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100" />
</label>
<label>
 <input class="checkbox-toggle" type="checkbox" name="img[0][1]" />
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/100" />
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/100" />
</label>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/etw6zxnL/5/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to edit this so it works perfectly :)